# Neo4j relationship creation

Tags: neo4j, relationships

Neo4J 2.0.3 Community version
Windows Server 2008 R2 ENT 64bit

Hi,
Im new to Neo4j and have been trying to load some data and relationships, but have hit a snag.
i have loaded 680,000 nodes using the load CSV command, and that works great.

> USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
>   "file:/c:/Import/CSVsForImport/AMRentLine.csv" AS csvLine CREATE
>   (p:AmRentLine { Rentid: csvLine.Rentid, Itemid: csvLine.Itemid, Name:
>   csvLine.Name, Qty: tofloat(csvLine.Qty)})

```
Sample Data:

Rentid          Itemid       Name               Qty
0123-014160     18/0165-h   TRENCH RAMMER        52
0123-014165     18/0168-h   TRENCH RAMMER        65
4290-014167     18/0165-h   TRENCH RAMMER        43
4290-014188     10/0385-h   PERCUSSION DRILL      5
4290-014190     10/0385-h   PERCUSSION DRILL     28
4290-014197     11/0155-h   HEAVY DUTY DRILL      4
```

Then I loaded Itemtab

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/c:/Import/CSVsForImport/Itemtab.csv" AS csvLine
create (i:Itemtab {Itemid: csvLine.Itemid})
```

Sample Item data

```
Itemid
18/0165-h
18/0168-h
10/0385-h
11/0155-h
15/0230-h
11/0120-h
11/0170-h
26/0090-h
15/0225-h
71/6250-h
01/0110-h
18/0300-h
9940344-h
26/0120-h
```

Then I tried to create relationships

> match (rl:AmRentLine),(it:Itemtab) where rl.Itemid = it.Itemid  merge
>   (it)-[:IsOnContract]->(rl)

this runs for hours and eventually finishes, in the Neo4j browser a relationship IsOnContract appears but when i try and query these relationships with

```
MATCH (a)-[:`IsOnContract`]->(b) RETURN a,b LIMIT 25
```

(Linkurious says there are 0 relationships BTW)

I get zero rows- i.e. the relationships dont exist.

Is there something i am doing wrong here?

I have also tried creating the relationships during the import of AmRentLine but with the same effect.

regards
Colin

Answer (score 0):

Colin,

I think you hit a memory issue.
And a cross-product.

So for once you can perhaps up your memory in neo4j-wrapper.conf ?

create index on :AmRentLine(Itemid);
create index on :Itemtab(Itemid);

Otherwise try to do the following:

```
match (rl:AmRentLine)
MATCH (it:Itemtab {ItemId:rl.ItemId})
merge (it)-[:IsOnContract]->(rl)
remove rl.ItemId
remove it.ItemId
```

or you can chunk up your work into smaller sections

```
match (rl:AmRentLine),(it:Itemtab) 
with rl,it
skip 200000 limit 100000
where rl.Itemid = it.Itemid 
merge (it)-[:IsOnContract]->(rl)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael, I will try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: Hi Michael,Sorry to be stupid, i cant find neo4j-wrapper.conf?